# After clicking Submit button for a quiz in php on wordpress, results of POST doesn't get displayed

Tags: php, wordpress, submit

I created a quiz in php with questions, I have added the php code shortcode on wordpress page. User should be able to answer the quiz which is in the form of picking a radio button. AFter user has answered all the questions, user clicks SUBMIT button, now the user should be displayed his score. The issue is user is not getting displayed the code.

The same php code when I execute on local php server that I set up, it works fine and provides the score. What am I missing here?

```
if (isset($_POST['answers']) && !empty($_POST['answers'])){
    $Answers = $_POST['answers']; // Get submitted answers.;
    header('location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    if ($Answers == 'NULL'){
            echo "please select all the answers";
    }
    else
    {
    foreach ($Questions as $QuestionNo => $Value){`enter code here`
        if (!isset($Answers[$QuestionNo])) {
            echo "answer all questions";
            break;

 ?>
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <?php foreach ($Questions as $QuestionNo => $Value){ ?>

        <h3><?php echo $Value['Question']; ?></h3>
        <?php
            foreach ($Value['Answers'] as $Letter => $Answer){
            $Label = 'question-'.$QuestionNo.'-answers-'.$Letter;
        ?>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="answers[<?php echo 
 $QuestionNo; ?>]" id="<?php echo $Label; ?>" value="<?php echo 
 $Answer; ?>" />
            <label for="<?php echo $Label; ?>"><?php echo $Letter; ? 
 >) <?php echo $Answer; ?> </label>
     </div>
        <?php } ?>

    <?php } ?>
            <br />
            <div>
            <input style="font-size:25px;color:white;background- 
  color:orange;border:2px solid #336600;padding:3px;" type="submit" 
  value="Submit Quiz" />
    </div>
    </form>
<?php
```

expected resulted is that after user answers all the quiz questions and clicks SUBMIT, the output of score should be displayed. The output doesn't get displayed instead the page is directed to home page of website.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's in there but I would try removing the below code. You want to show the answers but instead, you are redirecting the user to the page.

```
header('location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Comment: I removed the header line and that didn't fix the issue